# divide content into 2, and fill the contents in the whole body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make something like:

```
-----------------------
|  menubar            |
------------------------
|                     |
|                     |
|     50%  height,    |
|     100% width      |
|                     |
------------------------
|                     |
|                     |
|     50%  height,    |
|     100% width      |
|                     |
-------------------------
```

However, whenever I tried to set the contents height with 100%, it just disappeared.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;   <---------here, if I change is to height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#table {
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    background-color: yellow;
}

td {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

#tableholder {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

#canvasholder {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

This is my html

```
<body>

<nav id="menubar">
  <ul>
    <li>File
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:open()">Open</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:close()">Close</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Help
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:about()">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>         
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="content">
  <div id="tableholder"> 
  </div> 
  <div id="canvasholder">
  </div>
</section>

<input style="display:none;" id="fileDialog" type="file" />

</body>
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

the menu bar is okay, but I just want to divide the content area by .5 for 2 area.
One is for table, and the other is plot

Comment: Where is the style for menubar?

Answer (score 1):

Give a definite height for your `menubar` and then use `calc` to reduce that height from `100%` for the content area.

***Relevant CSS***:

```
#menubar {
    height: 64px;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 64px);   
    overflow: auto;
}
```

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rgn0pmmf/1/***

***Note***: As pointed out by @Ruddy, `calc` is CSS3 specific and will work only in modern browsers. If you need to support old/legacy browsers, then this will be a problem.

In that case, one simple alternative would be to use percent height for your menubar as well, and use the remaining height for the content.

.

Comment: You may want to point out that this is using CSS3 and calc has limited support.